# How to clear manual input date in angular ngx-mydatepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular12, ngx-mydatepicker

I am working in **ngx-mydatepicker** to select dates in my Angular(11) app. I followed the URL
https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker and I am able to get the datepicker as expected.

I have implemented the reactive forms in my application, I did the following changes. Datepicker is working fine when I am selecting the toggleCalender icon, and I am able to clear the date when clicking clearDate icon.

Problem is, when I am manually provide input for date it allows, then I am trying to clear the date, it actually clears from formControl, but in web page the provided date is still there, also I am trying to change the date from toggle icon and it is not changed in web page. still keeps the manual input date what I provided.

Did I miss something. I am using ngx-datepicker version 9.0.2

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, NgxMyDatePickerModule.forRoot() ],
    declarations: [ UserApp ],
    bootstrap:    [ UserApp ]
})
export class UserAppModule {}
```

My User HTML looks like below,

```
        <input class="form-control" style="float:none" placeholder="Select a date" ngx-mydatepicker name="myDate"
               formControlName="myDate" [options]="myOptions" #dp="ngx-mydatepicker"/>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dp.clearDate()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dp.toggleCalendar()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
```

My User Component Looks like below,

```
export class UserApp implements OnInit {

    myOptions: INgxMyDpOptions = {
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    };

    private myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            myDate: [null, Validators.required]
        });
    }

    clearDate(): void {
        // Clear the date using the patchValue function
        this.myForm.patchValue({myDate: null});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and I found the problem caused by this line of code
[setInputValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0Lw.png)

When you input a date manually, the control will run function `isDateValid()` [isDateValid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgR61.png) to check if input is valid. That function take `this.elem.nativeElement.value` but `this.elem.nativeElement.value != value` is assigned by `this.elem.nativeElement.setAttribute("value", value)`. That why once input invalid value, `this.elem.nativeElement.value` can not be update anymore;

My fixing is create new directive override `NgxMyDatePickerDirective` function `setInputValue`, change `this.elem.nativeElement.setAttribute("value", value)` to `this.elem.nativeElement.value = value`